# wxwidgets resize sizers after hiding/showing child controls

Tags: resize, wxwidgets, children, sizer

I have an wxWindow. Inside there I've got a wxBoxSize (Vertical). The sizer has 3 child controls.

I want to be able to hide one of the three child controls, and have the sizer and its parent automaticly resize. For example when I hide one child control of the sizer, the window decreases by 200 pixels.

Right now my method of showing hiding certain controls, and resizing the window looks like this: (Hardcoded, fugly)

```
void GenUIAanleverOptionsDialog::OnToggleButtonShowLabels( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    if(this->btnShowLabels->GetValue())
    {
        this->pnlInfoLabels->Show(true);
        this->SetSize(this->GetSize().GetWidth(), 573);
    }
    else
    {
        this->pnlInfoLabels->Show(false);
        this->SetSize(this->GetSize().GetWidth(), 294);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I found working for me was to Hide/Show the Sizer that contained the panel. After changing the visibility of the Sizer, a call to the Sizer's method  Layout() was necassary.

That however did not also adjust the position of the parent window, so a call to the wxWindow's Fit() method was necassary aswell.

Final code:

```
void GenUIStatusAanleverFrame::OnToggleButtonShowLabels( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    if(this->btnShowLabels->GetValue())
    {
        this->sizerInfoLabels->Show(true);
        this->sizerOverview->Layout();
    }
    else
    {
        this->sizerInfoLabels->Show(false);
        this->sizerOverview->Layout();
    }
    this->Fit();
}
```